# unique_ptr compile error

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, stl, unique-ptr

I guess this is embarrassing if I told you I cant get this to compile. would you please help me:

```
#include<memory>
using namespace std;

int  main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> p1(new int(5));
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc main.cpp 
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:6:2: error: ‘unique_ptr’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:6:13: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
main.cpp:6:13: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1
```

Comment: `gcc` is almost never used without passing some options. Try at least `g++ -std=c++0x -pedantic main.cpp`.

Comment: why do you use std:: if you have using namespace std; anyways?

Comment: thanks. it worked.  1- why don't you post an answer so that i can mark it as true. 2-while you are on it, would you please give me a short reason why gcc is never used(and g++ used instead) or perhaps link to a reference?  thanks

Comment: @rahman: `gcc` = C, `g++` = C++.

Comment: @AusCBloke gcc stands for Gnu Compiler Collection  , it auto-detects language based on file extension.  Although the use of `g++` is important if you're invoking it solely as the linker, when it can't deduce from extension.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is just a guess.

Most likely you compiled your program like this (or similarly) :

```
g++ main.cpp
```

If you did, then the problem is that g++ uses c++03 as default. To use c++11 features (and `std::unique_ptr`), you need to use newer version of c++ :

```
g++ -std=c++11
```

or

```
g++ -std=c++14
```

and I would recommend to use also `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but `-std=c++11` flag is enabled and all required headers are included. Can't get what's wrong: https://gist.github.com/canadien91/2ba3f9576823159c2d52

Comment: for future reference: @Montreal #include <memory>

Comment: @Stuck, hmm, in my gist <memory> is included. But I don't remember now when I have added this.

Comment: actually the gist link for me is a 404 error, so I only had a guess.. because I experienced the same problem. For me it would have been helpful to get that hint here beneath your comment.

Comment: Worth noting, the [std::make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) function requires c++14

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **Code::Blocks**, go to *Settings > Compiler > Global compiler settings > Compiler settings* and look for the *Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [`-std=c++11`]* and check it!

(**Code::Blocks** will add the `-std=c++11` for you when compiling)