# How to set the C++ standard in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I usually set the standard in Eclipse by adding -std=c++0x to `project properties --> C/C++ Build --> Settings --> Tool Settings --> Miscellaneous` . Are there other ways to set this?

Comment: What doesn't work with the way you do it?

Comment: @Mat it works, I was just wondering if there other ways to do this.

Comment: @Mat: Last time I checked this won't make eclipse recognize the new c++11 std library additions.

Comment: @KillianDS well you get some functionality, but not all of it. I can use the "auto" keyword.But I believe it depends on the specific compiler.

Comment: You should add `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` to  "Paths and Symbols" to recognize c++11 additions. See [http://stackoverflow.com/q/9766936/72178](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9766936/72178).

Comment: @ks1322 that's cool for auto-completion.

Comment: Just rephrase this as a Stackoverflow Question+Answer and harvest points.